# Set admin body to ltr on a rtl installation

Tags: admin, admin-css

I am using a *rtl* WordPress installation (Hebrew language) and have the following problem:

On the admin interface, most of the plugins I install do not have a *rtl* stylesheet and therefore the plugin interface is displayed in a distorted way.

It can be easily fixed using css - just set the `#wpbody` div to *ltr* like this:

```
#wpbody {
    direction:ltr !important;
}
```

But I can't find the right place / css file to make it work.
I have tried the following - unsuccesfully:

```
wp-admin-rtl.css
wp-admin.css
dashboard-rtl.css
dashboard.css
```

Any idea how to make it work?

Answer (score 2):

> **Important:** You shouldn't modify core files, because you might loose
>   all your edits in the next core upgrade.

You should instead enqueue your own stylesheet with your custom CSS modifications through the [`admin_enqueue_scripts`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/admin_enqueue_scripts) hook or use a hook like  `admin_head` to implement your customization.

Here's an example:

```
/**
 * Force #wpbody to the 'ltr' direction:
 */

add_action( 'admin_head', function(){
 echo '<style> #wpbody { direction:ltr !important; } </style>
';
});
```

These kind of modifications are suitable as a plugin. Create a file like `/wp-content/plugins/wpse-admin-ltr/wpse-admin-ltr.php`, with your code for modifications:

```
<?php
 /**
  * Plugin Name: WPSE - Force ltr admin layout
  * Author:      Yair Levy
  * Description: Force #wpbody to the 'ltr' direction:
  * Version:     0.0.1
  */

 // ----------- your custom code here -------------
```

Check the [Codex for more detailed instructions on how to write a plugin](http://codex.wordpress.org/Writing_a_Plugin).

Just remember to use the [`WP_DEBUG`](http://codex.wordpress.org/WP_DEBUG) on your dev site.

I hope this helps.